# How do I find the total of a specific row of a data frame in R?

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a data frame (df) that is a larger version of this:

```
txnID   date        product          sold   repID   lastName
1001    8/5/2020    Clobromizen      600    203     Kappoorthy
1002    6/28/2020   Alaraphosol      276    887     da Silva
1003    6/28/2020   Alaraphosol      184    887     da Silva
1004    4/16/2020   Diaprogenix       36    887     da Silva
1005    6/14/2020   Diaprogenix       40    887     da Silva
1006    5/19/2020   Xinoprozen      5640    332     McRowe
1007    8/23/2020   Diaprogenix       60    332     McRowe
1008    11/14/2020  Clobromizen     2880    332     McRowe
1009    9/26/2020   Colophrazen      738    203     Kappoorthy
1010    2/5/2020    Diaprogenix       20    332     McRowe
1011    9/23/2020   Gerantrazeophem 3740    100     Schwab
1012    12/4/2020   Clobromizen     1584    221     Sixt
```

I want to create a new data frame that takes the sum of all the sold products for each employee shown (All of the employees are shown), which would look something like this:

```
View(df1)
   lastName    totalSold
1  Kappoorthy  sum(df$sold)
2  da Silva    sum(df$sold)
3  McRowe      sum(df$sold)
4  Schwab      sum(df$sold)
5  Sixt        sum(df$sold)
```

Answer (score 2):

Here a way to do it with `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  filter(!(product %in% c("Xinoprozen", "Diaprogenix") )%>%
  group_by(lastName) %>% 
  summarize(totalSold = sum(sold,na.rm = TRUE))
```

Comment: let's say I want to exclude any sales of "Xinoprozen" and "Diaprogenix". How would that look implemented?

Answer (score 2):

```
library(dplyr) 

 df%>%
        group_by(lastName)%>%
        summarise(Totalsold = sum(sold))
```

if you want to exclude any of the products eg "Xinoprozen" and "Diaprogenix"

```
df%>%
    filter(!(product %in% c("Xinoprozen", product!="Diaprogenix")))%>%
    group_by(lastName)%>%
    summarise(Totalsold = sum(sold))
```

Comment: I don’t think that the second part of this will work as intended. I think you need to use e.g. `grepl`.

Answer (score 2):

in Base R you could do:

```
aggregate(sold~lastName, df, sum)

     lastName sold
1    da Silva  536
2 Kappoorthy  1338
3     McRowe  8600
4     Schwab  3740
5       Sixt  1584
```

To subset out the 2:

```
aggregate(sold~lastName, df, sum, subset = !product %in%c("Xinoprozen","Diaprogenix"))
     lastName sold
1    da Silva  460
2 Kappoorthy  1338
3     McRowe  2880
4     Schwab  3740
5       Sixt  1584
```

In case if you had `NA`s:

```
aggregate(sold~lastName, df, sum, na.rm =TRUE)
```

Answer (score 1):

using R base `aggregate`

```
aggregate(sold ~ lastName, sum, na.rm=TRUE, data=df)
```